# Deathloop voice confusion

Tags: video-games

> Voice 1: Who? Who are you?
> Voice 2: Who- who am I? My name. MY NAME? Sonuva- FUCK! WHat the fuck's my name?

At the 1:30 mark, who is telling this to who?
Is this only the voice of the player or is there another voice talking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LogicDictates comments, Colt narrates several of the bits of text he sees floating in the world, and the alternate selfs he interacts with are generally visible, so this does, indeed, seem like basically self-dialogue, albeit with the first bit being him reading someone else's words (which may be from an alternate self).

Comment: Watching the video, I think it's just him reading the message out loud, and then asking himself that question with his voice in a slightly different pitch. If it was an alternate version of himself, then why wasn't he visible, and why did the player character act like he was still alone, rather than acknowledging that someone else was there? He does run into an alternate version of himself at the 10:45 mark, and that version isn't just a disembodied voice, he's just as much a physical presence as the player character himself.

Comment: You know what? You're right. :) I'll modify my answer.

Comment: The floating texts are also his other selfs?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley: I haven't played the game, but from what I've seen, it seems likely.